# Which site is appropriate for asking questions about hand-held calculators?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

The question would be:

> I'm using a [Casio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casio#Calculators) *[fx-82MS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casio#Scientific_calculators)*. However, while I'm solving a complex equation, say the square root of (50^2+30^2+70^2), in case I miss the brackets, you have to put at the beginning, or any other character, I have to clear and retype the entire equation again.
>
> Is there a feature which can let me go back and to enter missing characters without deleting any of the existing ones?

I'm not sure whether [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) would be appropriate, since it's not a software issue.

Comment: What do you mean by *"software issue"*? - What is the relation to *[Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour)*? Do you mean *"since it's a software issue"* (the opposite)? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Have you tried to press left or right arrow on the big round replay button below the display?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, yeah I did. It didn't help.